# How can I add a file upload button to my C# web application?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, forms

I want to add a file upload button to my web application in Visual Studio using C# in order to allow for the user to browse for a picture on his PC to save it in database. It is like when you want to attach file when you’re sending an email.

How can I add a file upload button to my website?

Comment: <input type="file" name="theFile" /> if it's pure html; or `<asp:FileUpload ...` if it's Asp.Net web forms(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) beyond that can't help much more - you will need to provide more information.  Oh yeah don't forget `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the enclosing form as @Widor's answer says

Comment: 10x 7assoun it is working good

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://example.com">
<p>
Please specify a file:<br>
<input type="file" name="myfile">
</p>
<div><input type="submit" value="Send"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

In web application do you mean `asp.net` ?

If so, you can use [`File Upload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) control.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

On client side add this to your form:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

and on server side write this byte[] to a database field:

```
FileUpload1.FileBytes
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
```

indside a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the basic information on HTML input tag over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp). [Working example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_type_file)